# AWS Greengrass daemon failed to start - Failed to create overlay fs for container rootfs no such device

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to setup AWS Greengrass core on EC2 instance of Ubuntu 14.04.
Steps :

1) Created the machine.

2) Enabled RDP following the steps from https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-to-linux-desktop-from-windows/

3) Created a new greengrass group and core, and installed the certificates as per the tutorial : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/greengrass/latest/developerguide/gg-deploy-simple-lambda.html

(Followed this tutorial religiously, no chance of any configuration mistake)

But, I get the below error on starting the Greengrass core daemon:

```
:~/Desktop/greengrass$ sudo ./greengrassd start
Setting up greengrass daemon
Validating execution environment
Found cgroup subsystem: cpuset
Found cgroup subsystem: cpu
Found cgroup subsystem: cpuacct
Found cgroup subsystem: memory
Found cgroup subsystem: devices
Found cgroup subsystem: freezer
Found cgroup subsystem: blkio
Found cgroup subsystem: perf_event
Found cgroup subsystem: hugetlb

Starting greengrass daemon.....
Greengrass daemon 4866 failed to start
**Failed to create overlay fs for container rootfs no such device**
```

Googled the error, seems like some docker issue. Have no clue of what it is saying.
Kindly help!!

Comment: Well you say that you have followed the config religiously but i see you started wrong? The start of the article says supported instance is `X86_64
Amazon EC2 Instance - Amazon Linux - amzn-ami-hvm-2016.09.1.20170119-x86_64-ebs` So you need to use Amazon AMI for this and ubuntu AMI is probably not supported at all

Comment: Thanks a ton, skipped the first page :P :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well you say that you have followed the config religiously but i see you started wrong?

The start of the article says supported instance is `X86_64 Amazon EC2 Instance - Amazon Linux - amzn-ami-hvm-2016.09.1.20170119-x86_64-ebs`

So you need to use Amazon AMI for this and ubuntu AMI is probably not supported at all